# How i print specific information on Bash

Tags: string, bash, string-parsing

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Digite o IP"
read ip

iod= snmpwalk -v2c -c public "$ip":161 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5

echo "$iod"
```

OUTPUT

```
iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "Name"
```

I want just print the "name", I'm kinda new on bash scripting.
I apreciate an hand.
Thakyou.

Comment: In this Case: ```echo ${iod:30}``` or ```echo ${iod} | grep -o -E '["].*["]'```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Digite o IP"
read ip
iod= snmpwalk -v2c -c public "$ip":161 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5
echo "$iod" | sed -e 's/^.*STRING: //'
```

This outputs just "Name" with the supplied data. We use `sed` to remove anything before the "STRING: " including the search string itself.

```
echo 'iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 = STRING: "Name"'  | sed -e 's/^.*STRING: //'
"Name"
```